# Facebook Graph API /{group}/feed only lists posts posted by me

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm an admin of a Facebook group, and I want to get all the posts on the group. However, a GET request to graph.facebook.com/{group-id}/feed only gives me the posts that I posted. Also when I GET /{post}/comments, none of the comments list the author or any other user-related properties. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fulfilled the basic requirements? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#readperms

Comment: @CBroe Seems like my app doesn't have the Group API permission. But how am I supposed to give a screencast of how my app works if I need said permission to create my app?

Comment: You need to test & develop it using what info is available when you use your app admin account (resp any other accounts explicitly added as testers to your app), you will only get access to general user’s information after you got the feature approved in review.

Comment: @CBroe i have same problem that i can see only posts of the admin who generated user token, i don't see posts of other admins of the group. my app in development mode so all permissions need not be reviewed. As you said shouldn't the Group API feature available in dev mode ? if not how i add group api feature in the app user token like other permissions?? if that solves my problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'd appreciate some help with the same thing if you could share what you did to get it working.

Comment: Any news here. I am an admin of a facebook group but in developer mode i am getting only the posts that i posted.The group is open and i have all the permissions. Maybe my permissions need to be reviewed first ?

Comment: Sorry guys no updates, I ended up giving up on the project...